# Separate one AngularJS directive into more files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have build a complex directive with various types of features and the JS code has extended to 500 lines of code.

Is there any way to separate the functionality of a directive into multiple files.

NOTE: Using services doesn't allow the directive to appear more than once in the same view, due to services not being singleton.

In order to work in an actual example, I've created a simple directive with 3 simple functions:

```
angular
  .module("myApp")
  .directive("myDirective", myDirective);

function myDirective() {
  var template = 
  '<div style="font-size: {{vm.size}}; color: {{vm.color}}">{{vm.getUpperCase(vm.myText)}}</div>';
  var directive = {
    restrict: "EA",
    template: template,
    controller: myDirectiveCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myText: "@",
      color: "@",
      size: "@"
    },
  };
  return directive; 
}



function myDirectiveCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  init();

  vm.getUpperCase = getUpperCase;

  function init(){
    vm.color = getColor();
    vm.size = getSize();
  }

  function getUpperCase(text){
    return text.toUpperCase();
  }

  function getColor(){
    return vm.color ? vm.color : "#F12";
  }

  function getSize(){
    return vm.size ? vm.size : "30px";
  }
}
```

My aim is to separate the functionalities of the 3 functions and put them into their own file. Is this possible ?

Here's the link to the plunkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/9tQzubu4qxudKkXIr5HK?p=preview

Comment: I don't really understand why you can't use services... That should be the way to do it: your `getColor`, `getSize`... functions have to be part of a service, or factory. Furthermore, they would be better tested that way.

Comment: That's not necessarily true, @SinDeus.  Services are good for data that you want to share across multiple directives; here it looks like the data is best stored inside the directive so that each one can have its own color/size/etc.

Comment: Yes, but they can also provide utility functions. For example, your `getUpperCase` function. And you can keep your data stored in your directive with the other functions (i.e. `getColor`) with a little adaptation: `service.getColor = function (vm) { return vm.color ? vm.color : DEFAULT_COLOR; }`. What do you think?

Comment: For some reason, I haven't thought of handing out the whole vm to the service function, thus generalizing the functionality of the service. I have since changed my approach in my directive.
If you think it's worth it, feel free to formulate this as an answer. :)